# Iterate through nested data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, reactjs

I have the following data structure:

```
{  
   "data":[  
      {  
         "id":1,
         "name":"EU Group",
         "parent_id":null,
         "children":[  
            {  
               "id":2,
               "name":"EMEA Branch",
               "parent_id":1,
               "children":[  
                  {  
                     "id":5,
                     "name":"UK",
                     "parent_id":2,
                     "lr":","
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":6,
                     "name":"France",
                     "parent_id":2,
                     "lr":","
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":7,
                     "name":"Germany",
                     "parent_id":2,
                     "lr":","
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":8,
                     "name":"Spain",
                     "parent_id":2,
                     "lr":","
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":9,
                     "name":"Finland",
                     "parent_id":2,
                     "lr":","
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":10,
                     "name":"Hungary",
                     "parent_id":2,
                     "lr":","
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":11,
                     "name":"Poland",
                     "parent_id":2,
                     "children":[  
                        {  
                           "id":25,
                           "name":"Romania",
                           "parent_id":11,
                           "lr":","
                        }
                     ],
                     "lr":","
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":12,
                     "name":"Sweden",
                     "parent_id":2,
                     "lr":","
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":16,
                     "name":"Italy",
                     "parent_id":2,
                     "lr":","
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":17,
                     "name":"Czech",
                     "parent_id":2,
                     "lr":","
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":18,
                     "name":"Denmark",
                     "parent_id":2,
                     "lr":","
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":19,
                     "name":"Rest of the world",
                     "parent_id":2,
                     "lr":","
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":36,
                     "name":"Middle East",
                     "parent_id":2,
                     "children":[  
                        {  
                           "id":21,
                           "name":"Russia",
                           "parent_id":36,
                           "lr":","
                        }
                     ],
                     "lr":","
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":38,
                     "name":"Africa",
                     "parent_id":2,
                     "children":[  
                        {  
                           "id":49,
                           "name":"Algeria",
                           "parent_id":38,
                           "lr":","
                        },
                        {  
                           "id":50,
                           "name":"Morocco",
                           "parent_id":38,
                           "lr":","
                        }
                     ],
                     "lr":","
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":48,
                     "name":"Belgium",
                     "parent_id":2,
                     "lr":","
                  }
               ],
               "lr":","
            },
            {  
               "id":45,
               "name":"International Branch",
               "parent_id":1,
               "lr":","
            },
            {  
               "id":46,
               "name":"APAC Branch",
               "parent_id":1,
               "children":[  
                  {  
                     "id":51,
                     "name":"Singapore",
                     "parent_id":46,
                     "lr":","
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":52,
                     "name":"China",
                     "parent_id":46,
                     "lr":","
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":53,
                     "name":"Vietnam",
                     "parent_id":46,
                     "lr":","
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":54,
                     "name":"Indonesia",
                     "parent_id":46,
                     "lr":","
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":55,
                     "name":"India",
                     "parent_id":46,
                     "lr":","
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":56,
                     "name":"Malaysia",
                     "parent_id":46,
                     "lr":","
                  }
               ],
               "lr":","
            }
         ],
         "lr":","
      }
   ]
}
```

I am trying to iterate over it using this function I created:

```
buildHierarchy(item) {
    zone.children.forEach((child) => {
        this.buildHierarchy(child);
    })
}
```

Which is called further down in my render function:

```
render() {
    ...
    if (zones[0]) {
        this.buildHierarchy(zones);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

However this breaks when it hits an item that has no children. How can I get this to work?

Comment: Just add and if to check if there are children?

Comment: you should check if  zone.children is null?

Comment: @Leon but it will break out of the loop and potentially miss other items that may or may not have children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the check on children before using `forEach` on that:

```
buildHierarchy(zone) {
    if(zone && zone.children) 
       zone.children.forEach(child => { this.buildHierarchy(child) })
}
```

I think there is a mismatch, you need to receive `zone` instead of `item` in `buildHierarchy` method.

Check this code:

```js
let data = {
   "data":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "name":"EU Group",
         "parent_id":null,
         "children":[
            {
               "id":2,
               "name":"EMEA Branch",
               "parent_id":1,
               "children":[
                  {
                     "id":5,
                     "name":"UK",
                     "parent_id":2,
                     "lr":","
                  },
                  {
                     "id":6,
                     "name":"France",
                     "parent_id":2,
                     "lr":","
                  },
                  {
                     "id":7,
                     "name":"Germany",
                     "parent_id":2,
                     "lr":","
                  },
                  {
                     "id":8,
                     "name":"Spain",
                     "parent_id":2,
                     "lr":","
                  },
                  {
                     "id":9,
                     "name":"Finland",
                     "parent_id":2,
                     "lr":","
                  },
                  {
                     "id":10,
                     "name":"Hungary",
                     "parent_id":2,
                     "lr":","
                  },
                  {
                     "id":11,
                     "name":"Poland",
                     "parent_id":2,
                     "children":[
                        {
                           "id":25,
                           "name":"Romania",
                           "parent_id":11,
                           "lr":","
                        }
                     ],
                     "lr":","
                  },
                  {
                     "id":12,
                     "name":"Sweden",
                     "parent_id":2,
                     "lr":","
                  },
                  {
                     "id":16,
                     "name":"Italy",
                     "parent_id":2,
                     "lr":","
                  },
                  {
                     "id":17,
                     "name":"Czech",
                     "parent_id":2,
                     "lr":","
                  },
                  {
                     "id":18,
                     "name":"Denmark",
                     "parent_id":2,
                     "lr":","
                  },
                  {
                     "id":19,
                     "name":"Rest of the world",
                     "parent_id":2,
                     "lr":","
                  },
                  {
                     "id":36,
                     "name":"Middle East",
                     "parent_id":2,
                     "children":[
                        {
                           "id":21,
                           "name":"Russia",
                           "parent_id":36,
                           "lr":","
                        }
                     ],
                     "lr":","
                  },
                  {
                     "id":38,
                     "name":"Africa",
                     "parent_id":2,
                     "children":[
                        {
                           "id":49,
                           "name":"Algeria",
                           "parent_id":38,
                           "lr":","
                        },
                        {
                           "id":50,
                           "name":"Morocco",
                           "parent_id":38,
                           "lr":","
                        }
                     ],
                     "lr":","
                  },
                  {
                     "id":48,
                     "name":"Belgium",
                     "parent_id":2,
                     "lr":","
                  }
               ],
               "lr":","
            },
            {
               "id":45,
               "name":"International Branch",
               "parent_id":1,
               "lr":","
            },
            {
               "id":46,
               "name":"APAC Branch",
               "parent_id":1,
               "children":[
                  {
                     "id":51,
                     "name":"Singapore",
                     "parent_id":46,
                     "lr":","
                  },
                  {
                     "id":52,
                     "name":"China",
                     "parent_id":46,
                     "lr":","
                  },
                  {
                     "id":53,
                     "name":"Vietnam",
                     "parent_id":46,
                     "lr":","
                  },
                  {
                     "id":54,
                     "name":"Indonesia",
                     "parent_id":46,
                     "lr":","
                  },
                  {
                     "id":55,
                     "name":"India",
                     "parent_id":46,
                     "lr":","
                  },
                  {
                     "id":56,
                     "name":"Malaysia",
                     "parent_id":46,
                     "lr":","
                  }
               ],
               "lr":","
            }
         ],
         "lr":","
      }
   ]
}

function buildHierarchy(item){
   console.log('name', item.name);
   if(item && item.children){        
        item.children.forEach(el=>buildHierarchy(el));
    }
}

buildHierarchy(data.data[0]);
```

Comment: Now I'm getting: item.children.foreach is not a function, because it is reaching an item that has no children, but it needs to keep going to process the next item.

Comment: @imperium2335 you are getting this error, because `foreach` is not a function. You need `forEach`.

Comment: @DeividasKaržinauskas thanks for pointing it out, silly mistake :)